# Coldfusion Gateway New type: Unable to find or load Gateway class

Tags: java, coldfusion, gateways

Playing around with ColdFusion gateways, I ran into a problem. Following the steps from [this document](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=CreateGateways_5.html#117324), I put my jar file into the `gateway\lib` folder. I then restarted my server and tried to add the gateway to my list of gateways already installed. (Mind you, I did not install the gateways that were already on this system.) 
I get the error:

> Error creating gateway type.
>
> Unable to find or load Gateway class [my entered class name here.]

Adding a new gateway with a classname that is already in the list, but with a new Name successfully creates a new gateway. So there's nothing (much) wrong with my administrator interface.

I've compiled the Java code with Netbeans. Added the jar file to the `gateway\lib` directory and restarted the server. (Even restarted the computer to be sure....) 
I've verified that I compile and run with the same Java version: 1.7.0_45.

Opening my jar file with Zip and comparing it to a known working jar file shows no real differences in structure. Nor is there an major difference in the manifest. The manifest file in my project shows a newer Ant version, but that's all.

To compile the project, I imported cfusion.jar from: C:\JRun4\servers\cfusion\cfusion-ear\cfusion-war\WEB-INF\cfusion\lib\cfusion.jar

This seemed to satisfy all of the required imports in the project. I then compiled the jar file successfully. Am I missing something? Should there be other things linked in there as well?

Are there other things I can check? Log files don't really tell me anything.

Thanks in advance for any pointers you can give me..

Comment: `I've compiled the Java code with Netbeans`. I think this is not the thing you are really know and this may be mistaken. `Java` compiler compile `Java` code and `Netbeans` is just an `IDE`.

Comment: Did you follow [the documentation to build your event gateway](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=CreateGateways_4.html)?

Comment: Ruchira, I am well aware of the fact that Netbens is an IDE and not a compiler. However common part of an IDE is that it can compile code. Implicitly I meant that I used Netbeans, that in turn uses its builtin compiler, to compile the service into a jar. My Apologies if this wasn't entirely clear.

Comment: Miguel-F, Basically what I did was take CF's example code for the 'EmptyGateway' in C:\JRun4\servers\cfusion\cfusion-ear\cfusion-war\WEB-INF\cfusion\gateway\src\examples\EmptyGateway.java and turned it into my own code. I've rechecked to make sure all methods as described in the 'howto build' are in fact there. Alas, no dice.